# MySQL socket disappears

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, apache2, php7, mediawiki, mysql5

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with MySQL server for MediaWiki 1.30.0 along with Apache2 and PHP7.0. The installation was successful for everything, I managed to get it all running. Then I start installing extensions for MediaWiki. Everything is fine until I install the Virtual Editor extension. It requires that I have both Parsoid and RESTBase installed. So I install those along side Virtual Editor. Then I go to check my wiki and see this message (database name for the wiki is "bible"):

> Sorry! This site is experiencing technical difficulties.
>
> Try waiting a few minutes and reloading.
>
> (Cannot access the database: Unknown database 'bible' (localhost))
>
> Backtrace:
>
> #0 /var/www/html/w/includes/libs/rdbms/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.php(1028): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->reportConnectionError('Unknown databas...')
>
> #1 /var/www/html/w/includes/libs/rdbms/loadbalancer/LoadBalancer.php(670): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer->reportConnectionError()
>
> #2 /var/www/html/w/includes/GlobalFunctions.php(2858): Wikimedia\Rdbms\LoadBalancer->getConnection(0, Array, false)
>
> #3 /var/www/html/w/includes/user/User.php(493): wfGetDB(-1)
>
> #4 /var/www/html/w/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(892): User->{closure}(false, 3600, Array, NULL)
>
> #5 /var/www/html/w/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(1012): WANObjectCache->{closure}(false, 3600, Array, NULL)
>
> #6 /var/www/html/w/includes/libs/objectcache/WANObjectCache.php(897): WANObjectCache->doGetWithSetCallback('global:user:id:...', 3600, Object(Closure), Array, NULL)
>
> #7 /var/www/html/w/includes/user/User.php(520): WANObjectCache->getWithSetCallback('global:user:id:...', 3600, Object(Closure), Array)
>
> #8 /var/www/html/w/includes/user/User.php(441): User->loadFromCache()
>
> #9 /var/www/html/w/includes/user/User.php(405): User->loadFromId(0)
>
> #10 /var/www/html/w/includes/session/UserInfo.php(88): User->load()
>
> #11 /var/www/html/w/includes/session/CookieSessionProvider.php(119): MediaWiki\Session\UserInfo::newFromId('1')
>
> #12 /var/www/html/w/includes/session/SessionManager.php(487): MediaWiki\Session\CookieSessionProvider->provideSessionInfo(Object(WebRequest))
>
> #13 /var/www/html/w/includes/session/SessionManager.php(190): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager->getSessionInfoForRequest(Object(WebRequest))
>
> #14 /var/www/html/w/includes/WebRequest.php(735): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager->getSessionForRequest(Object(WebRequest))
>
> #15 /var/www/html/w/includes/session/SessionManager.php(129): WebRequest->getSession()
>
> #16 /var/www/html/w/includes/Setup.php(762): MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager::getGlobalSession()
>
> #17 /var/www/html/w/includes/WebStart.php(114): require_once('/var/www/html/w...')
>
> #18 /var/www/html/w/index.php(40): require('/var/www/html/w...')
>
> #19 {main}

I checked the error logs in MySQL, and the error message said that the database was trying to be accessed without a password. I restarted my computer and restarted Apache, Parsoid, RESTBase, and MySQL. But I could not successfully restart MySQL. The error log by typing the command `journalctl -xe` and saw that it failed to start because it couldn't write to `/var/lib/mysql/`. I went to StackExchange to see if I could a solution, and one answer said to use the command `mysql -u root -p`. I did and typed in the password and it gave this error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I also check the status of it by typing `sudo mysqladmin status` which said:

> mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
>   error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
>   Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

I wanted to verify that it existed, but upon browsing to the location of the socket, I found it was not there. I saw an answer about a missing MySQL socket which said to use the `touch` command to create the socket and another file. I did it and still had the same issues. I went back to the directory and found the two files to be missing. So I created them again with the `touch` command and watched the folder to see what happens. After about half a minute, the folder seems to be deleted and recreated. I get kicked out of the folder into it's parent directory and when I go back in the files are gone.

Does anybody know why this is happening, or at least how I can fix this and get MySQL back up and running?

Comment: My immediate thought is that `/var/lib/mysql` isn't writable or is being protected by something, or there is an underlying hardware problem. Can you try touching a plain file, and also give use some idea of your hardware setup.

Comment: @SimonGreenwood I am thinking that it has something to do with the folder being protected. I don't know what is protecting it nor how to find out. There also seems to be something controlling the folder containing the sockets but I don't know how to find out. When I get a chance to experiment on my computer, I will let you know what happens. I have never used touch before, so that is new for me.

Comment: Apparmor may be running although MySQL usually has a profile. You can try running `apparmor_status`.